# Terraform module s3 lifecycle rule not not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a s3 lifecycle rule that should delete the failed multipart upload after n number of days by using lifecycle rules. I want to use `lookup` instead of `try`

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration" "default" {

  count    = length(var.lifecycle_rule) != 0 ? 1 : 0
  bucket   = aws_s3_bucket.bucket.bucket
  dynamic "rule" {
    for_each = try(jsondecode(var.lifecycle_rule), var.lifecycle_rule)

    content {
      id     = lookup(rule.value, "id", "default")
      status = lookup(rule.value, "status", "Enabled")


      dynamic "abort_incomplete_multipart_upload" {
        for_each = lookup(rule.value, "abort_incomplete_multipart_upload", null) != null ? [rule.value.abort_incomplete_multipart_upload] : []
        content {
          days_after_initiation = abort_incomplete_multipart_upload.value.days_after_initiation
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I try to use this module resource in my child module, it does not work

```
module "test" {

  source  = "./s3"

  bucket_name = "test"
  lifecycle_rule = [
    {
      expiration = {
        days = 7
        
      }
    },
    {
      id = "abort-incomplete-multipart-upload-lifecyle-rule"
        abort_incomplete_multipart_upload_days =  {
          days_after_initiation = 6
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

terraform plan gives me

```
+ rule {
      + id     = "abort-incomplete-multipart-upload-lifecyle-rule"
      + status = "Enabled"

      + filter {
        }
    }
```

expected output:

```
  + rule {
          + id     = "abort-incomplete-multipart-upload-lifecyle-rule"
          + status = "Enabled"

          + abort_incomplete_multipart_upload {
              + days_after_initiation = 8
            }

          + filter {
            }
        }
```

Comment: It seems you are omitting some parts that might be important, e.g., the `rule` block. It would be beneficial to see that as well. Please add it to the question.

Comment: can you check now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the code that works:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration" "default" {

  count  = length(var.lifecycle_rule) != 0 ? 1 : 0
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.bucket.bucket
  dynamic "rule" {
    for_each = try(jsondecode(var.lifecycle_rule), var.lifecycle_rule)

    content {
      id     = lookup(rule.value, "id", "default")
      status = lookup(rule.value, "status", "Enabled")


      dynamic "abort_incomplete_multipart_upload" {
        for_each = lookup(rule.value, "abort_incomplete_multipart_upload_days", null) != null ? [rule.value.abort_incomplete_multipart_upload_days] : []
        content {
          days_after_initiation = abort_incomplete_multipart_upload.value.days_after_initiation
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

There are basically two issues:

1. The `lookup` was looking for a non-existing key in your map, `abort_incomplete_multipart_upload`, instead of `abort_incomplete_multipart_upload_days`
2. Because of the first error, it was propagated to the value you wanted, i.e., `rule.value.abort_incomplete_multipart_upload` instead of `rule.value.abort_incomplete_multipart_upload_days`

This code yields the following output:

```
  # aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration.default[0] will be created
  + resource "aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration" "default" {
      + bucket = (known after apply)
      + id     = (known after apply)

      + rule {
          + id     = "default"
          + status = "Enabled"
        }
      + rule {
          + id     = "abort-incomplete-multipart-upload-lifecyle-rule"
          + status = "Enabled"

          + abort_incomplete_multipart_upload {
              + days_after_initiation = 6
            }
        }
    }
```

However, if you want it to be one rule (i.e., the example output you want), you need to make a change to your `lifecycle_rule` variable:

```
  lifecycle_rule = [
    {
      expiration = {
        days = 7

      }
      id = "abort-incomplete-multipart-upload-lifecyle-rule"
      abort_incomplete_multipart_upload_days = {
        days_after_initiation = 6
      }
    }
  ]
```

This gives:

```
  + resource "aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration" "default" {
      + bucket = (known after apply)
      + id     = (known after apply)

      + rule {
          + id     = "abort-incomplete-multipart-upload-lifecyle-rule"
          + status = "Enabled"

          + abort_incomplete_multipart_upload {
              + days_after_initiation = 6
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there a way I can optimise it?

Comment: the code works.

Comment: How can I optimise it. Can I use this with lookup https://github.com/clouddrove/terraform-aws-s3/blob/master/main.tf#L226 instaed of try

Comment: I don't think you can. You would have to understand what `try` does first: https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/try. Also, the original question was answered, so I would suggest asking a new question, but I don't think you will get too far by asking for code optimisation on SO. I suggest you take a look at how the lifecycle rules are defined in that module and then try to replicate that: https://github.com/clouddrove/terraform-aws-s3/blob/master/_example/complete/example.tf#L100-L145.